# Webservice nusoap no procesa string xml si tiene la declaración xml version - encoding

Tags: php, xml, webservice

Tengo un webservice en php con nusoap al cual le llega *un string* que contiene un XML, con este formato:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><nodo1><subnodo1><id>id1</id><otherParams>1|2|3</otherParams></subnodo1></nodo1>
```

Mi webservice tiene el siguiente código:

```
$server = new soap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("Metodo");
$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $namespace;

$server->register('Metodo', array('xmlData'=>'xsd:string'), array('return'=>'xsd:string'), $namespace);

function Metodo($xmlData)
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlData);
    $idValue = $xml->subnodo1->id;
    return $idValue;
}
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

Si envío el parámetro $xmlData **sin la declaración** *xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"*, **todo funciona perfecto**. Pero el cliente envía el dato con la declaración.

Por otra parte, si creo un cliente de prueba y leo el string dentro del mismo cliente, lo parsea bien. Por ej:

```
$xmlAsString ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><nodo1><subnodo1><id>id1</id><otherParams>1|2|3</otherParams></subnodo1></nodo1>';
$xml1 = simplexml_load_string($xmlAsString);
$idValue = $xml1->subnodo1->id;
echo $idValue; //retorna el valor "id1"
```

Conclusión: el problema es al enviar el string al webservice, con la declaración.

El error que da $cliente->getError() es *HTTP Error: Unsupported HTTP response status 403 Forbidden (soapclient->response has contents of the response)*.

Cualquier sugerencia y/o ayuda es muy bienvenida. Gracias por leer!!